# Displaying NSPanel as a sheet creating offset

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspanel

I'm using this code to show a panel :

```
- (void)displayPanelWithView:(NSView *)view andTitle:(NSString *)title {
    [panel setTitle:title];    
    if ([windows count] < 1) {
        [panel setContentSize:[view frame].size];
        [panel setContentView:view];
        [panel center];
        [panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
    else {
        [panel setContentSize:[view frame].size];
        [panel setContentView:view];
        [NSApp beginSheet:panel modalForWindow:[windows objectAtIndex:0] modalDelegate:self     didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:NULL];
    }
}
```

`panel` is an IBOutlet (it is instantiated in IB). It is a subclass of NSPanel.

`windows` is an array of windows. If there are no windows, the panel is shown as a new window.

**The problem**

When I display a panel with a certain view, and `windows` is *not* empty, the panel is shown as a sheet. The first time this happens, there is always an offset. What follows are screenshots of the first time the method is called, and the second time it is called (both with `windows` not empty) :

[image: First time]

[image: Second time]

This error can go away if I use this :

```
[panel setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
```

In that case the size is correct, BUT the sheet is not focused anymore and stays unfocused (so the blue button in the above screenshots is white all the time).
What can I do to get the sheet to display right every time? What happens that first time that doesn't happen the next time?

Comment: More information is needed, for instance, do you use layout constraints or springs and struts to manage layout? And what are the relevant ones set to?

Comment: At any rate, it does seem like an invitation to problems like this to set the panel size from the size of a view that you reuse. What if the UI is changed to allow the user to re-size the panel? I'd prefer to just store the desired view dimensions in an ivar (or property for people so inclined) and set the size from that value.

Comment: No layout constraints. The view is 400x426 in size, the code above is what I use. There is one panel, 5 different views. All of them are IBOutlets. This way I don't have to create a new panel every time I display one of the views. It's only a small, non-important part of the app so it doesn't have to be perfectly written - as long as it works I'm happy.

Comment: I've edited the post - apparently it only happens with sheets and currently it only offsets the first time I display the view - not the second, third, ... time

Comment: what happens if you instantiate the panel fresh within the call rather than recycling? and how do you instantiate the panel in the first place?

Comment: Same thing happens. The panel is instantiated with IB (it's an IBOutlet).

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the issue by using this code instead :

```
- (void)displayPanelWithView:(NSView *)view andTitle:(NSString *)title {
    [panel setTitle:title];    
    if (![defaults floatForKey:@"SS_Interface_Mode"] == 0 || [windows count] < 1) {
        [panel setContentSize:[view frame].size];
        [[panel contentView] addSubview:view];
        [panel center];
        [panel makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    }
    else {
        [panel setContentSize:[view frame].size];
        [[panel contentView] addSubview:view];
        [NSApp beginSheet:panel modalForWindow:[windows objectAtIndex:0] modalDelegate:self didEndSelector:nil contextInfo:NULL];
    }
}
- (IBAction)endSheet:(id)sender {
    [NSApp endSheet:panel];
    [panel orderOut:nil];
    for (NSView *view in [[panel contentView] subviews])
        [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

As you can see, I add the view to the current content view of the panel instead of assigning it as the new content view of the panel.